# setting body font-size on a colorbox iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, colorbox

The site has a body{font-size:__px;) dynamically set using jQuery based on the window dimensions.
An onclick function opens a colorbox that contains an iframe:

```
$.fn.colorbox({iframe: true, href: $url, <?PHP print COLORBOX_OPTIONS; ?> });
```

I want to set the  body{font-size:--px;}  of the iframe to be the same as the current parent body{font-size:--px;}
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute this code inside the iframe which will set it's body's `font-size` as parent window's body's `font-size`.

```
$(function(){
   $('body').css('font-size', $('body', window.parent).css('font-size'));
});
```

Comment: within my iframe':  $(document).ready(function() {} . I put your code (with the corrected single quote on body!), it didn't seem to work unfortunately

Comment: If the parent body has font-size set then it should work fine. You don't need ` $(document).ready(function(){})` in iframe. My code has take care of executing it on page load `$(function(){})` is equivalent to that.

Comment: It may be working, but not as needed. the iframe has the same font-size (10px) as the parent body css font-size (10px) but not the dynamicaly set font-size (11px) on the body element of the parent!

Comment: both pages share a common style sheet so I am not sure if the iframe body font-size is reset by the script or just using the common stylesheet.

Comment: pop this into firebug or chrome tools and see if you get any results

" document.body.style.fontSize "

Comment: yes that is showing the correct dynamically set body font-size on the parent (11px)

Comment: by the way @ShankarSangoli i did pick up the missing the single quote on second mention of body before your correction/edit and have tried that

Comment: Thanks to both @ShankarSangoli and @Philip the following seems to be working:
`code` $(function(){
   $('body').css('font-size', parent.document.body.style.fontSize);
});

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Off the top of my head, not tested!

*after $.colorbox();*

**append this**

```
var bdFontSize = document.body.style.fontSize,
    targetIframe = $("iframe"),
    targetIframeHeadStyle = targetIframe.contents()
                                        .find("head")
                                        .append("<style></style>")
                                        .children("style");
```

-

EDIT: **BAD**

```
 targetIframeHeadStyle.html("
    body{
      font-size: "+bdFontSize+"
    }

");
```

**GOOD**

```
    targetIframeHeadStyle.html("body{font-size: "+bdFontSize+"}");
```

lets us know how you get on.

Comment: I am not sure when to call this, the iframe does not exist until the colorbox function is called. i understand this is the target, but am unsure aabout how to use it ! Thanks

Comment: I repeat a comment from the above answer: Thanks to both @ShankarSangoli and @Philip the following seems to be working:
`code` $(function(){
   $('body').css('font-size', parent.document.body.style.fontSize);
});